# Income boosting Special cards in Illuminati: Y2K

Tags: illuminati

I recently picked up the [Illuminati: Y2K](http://www.sjgames.com/illuminati/y2k/) expansion for Illuminati. I'm a little confused about the "double Income" Special cards. These cards say: "Play this card at any time to give all your FOO groups extra income equal to TWICE their normal income", where FOO is an Alignment.(Shown [here](http://www.sjgames.com/illuminati/y2k/cards.html) is a sample image of Flower Power, the double Income card for Peaceful groups.)

1) Do you place the extra MegaBucks(MBs) on your Peaceful groups right away or do you have to wait until they would normally get their Income again, on your next turn? Other Special cards that add MBs state they're added right away, and don't reference Income at all.

2) Do these cards permanently change the Income of those groups, or is this just a one-time deal? Again, because changing Income is different than just adding MB, I'm not sure what the correct way to use them is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cards are a one-time effect.  Whenever you play it, collect income twice for each aligned group.

From the [rules](http://www.sjgames.com/illuminati/img/illuminati_rules.pdf):

> 1. Collect Income. For each Group that has an
>      Income, draw that income from the bank. Put the
>      money directly on that card

Comment: Thanks Pat. Do you have a link to those rules? I couldn't find them.

Comment: @Discord - added link to rules.